# Kubernetes on Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I successfully deployed a kubernetes cluster of 3 nodes in Azure. I saw in the resource group that there were only 1 master created (same as with kubeadm).

[image]

Do someone know if we can have a cluster of more than one master to ensure a high availability kubernetes cluster ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the ACS engine currently supports HA for the kubernetes master. https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine

At this time, you will need to create a cluster manually using the HA documentation on the kubernetes website

I know that kops will be supporting Azure in their next major release : https://github.com/kubernetes/kops, not sure if they will have HA support at the beginning

Currently we are using our on-premise installer on pre-provisioned machines in Azure to get what we think is a production ready cluster.

Comment: i discussed with azure teams. They will release a new version of their azure container service with HA support and new management input such as scaling the number of nodes automatically.

Today, they provide https://github.com/vglafirov/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/coreos-kubernetes-multimaster o have a multi master  cluster ready.

Comment: thanks a lot for that link! how did you get in touch with an Azure/Kubernetes expert ? using the internal portal support request ? or another medium ? We are starting to go into Azure and would surely love to get this type of early access to new features.